# Short story - conspiracy to stop authors who are too good

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

This one may be from F&SF or Asimovs.  The story involves a writer who accidentally kills a bike-riding kid.  Then someone comes to his house and offers to erase the accident from history (and indicates that the accident had been arranged), if the author stops writing.  Other authors are also mentioned who had been suppressed by this organization (Perelman or Wodehouse were mentioned as authors who had been persuaded to switch to less dangerous (humorous) work).

Comment: This may be considered too off-topic, but if you liked that story I would suggest a fun and quirky movie called [Frequently Asked Questions About Time Travel](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0910554/).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is *[Prior Restraint](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?43673)* by Orson Scott Card.

A lot of the details have been given already, both in the question and the comments. The main character is an aspiring author, who meets a student called Doc Murphy in a writing class. Although Doc writes amazingly well, he never has anything published, and indeed seems never to complete an assignment.
The reason is that he was paid a visit by the "Censorship Board". As in the question, the Board altered time so that Doc ended up running over a boy on a bicycle:

> We had to try four times to get the timing right, but we finally made
> it. It's the nice thing about time travel. If you blow it, you can
> always go back and get it right the next time."

What was the point of it. Well,

> the boy was even more talented than anyone thought. He was going to
> grow up and be a writer. A journalist and critic. And he was going to
> cause a lot of problems for a particular government some forty years
> down the line. He was especially going to write three books that would
> change the whole way of thinking of a large number of people. The
> wrong way.

It is explained that the Censorship Board sends agents through time, in particular to make adjustments by ensuring various writers stop writing. For the particular case of Doc it was to avoid the depressive effects of his articles on the world.

> the trouble is, Murphy, you're a godawful hedonist and a pessimist to
> boot, and if we can just keep you from publishing anything, the whole
> artistic mood of two centuries will be brightened considerably. Not to
> mention the prevention of a famine in seventy years.

The agent tells Doc about various other writers they coerced. Perelman was indeed one of them (though Wodehouse was not mentioned), together with several other notable names:

> They tried to console me by telling me what good company I was in.
> **Thomas Hardy** -- they made him give up novels and stick to poetry which
> nobody read and so it was safe. Meek tells me, "**Hemingway** decided to
> kill himself instead of waiting for us to do it. And there are some
> others who only had to refrain from writing a particular book. It hurt
> them, but **Fitzgerald** was still able to have a decent career with the
> other books he could write, and **Perelman** gave it to us in laughs,
> since he couldn't be allowed to write his real work. We only bother
> with great writers. Bad writers aren't a threat to anybody."

The full text is available on [Card's website](http://www.hatrack.com/osc/stories/prior-restraint.shtml).

Comment: That's it!  Thank you

Comment: I kind of knew this would be an Orson Scott Card story - he's touched on that theme numerous times, that of a writer or artist forbidden from practicing their craft in some way or another.  I believe he's stated in interviews that being prevented from writing would be his greatest nightmare.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman OSC has also been condemned for various statements he has made in public, so themes of being forbidden from writing may have some roots in that. (I'll leave it up to the student to do their own research on OSC's position on certain matters)

Comment: @PeterM Oh, I'm well aware of these.  But I think that theme goes back to long before he made those statements.  I had a book of some of his earliest short stories - *Unaccompanied Sonata*, the title story of which dealt with this theme, in this case relating to a musician who was legally barred from making music.  It's been a running theme his whole career.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Well, d'uh!  Obviously then someone from the future warned him at the start of his career that words have consequences! (But point taken)